# MySQL procedure keep returns 0

Tags: java, mysql

don't know why, but i'm keep getting 0 as output parameter...
I ran the following :

```
INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, image, date_of_registration)
 VALUES ("xx", "xx", "xxx", null, sysdate());SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

and I got good result (!= 0) than I assume that `PersistentConnections` is set to `true`. any other configs that might causing this?

procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS partners.create_user;
CREATE DEFINER=`partnersmaster`@`%` PROCEDURE `create_user`(
  IN p_first_name NVARCHAR(30),
  IN p_last_name NVARCHAR(30),
  IN p_email NVARCHAR(100),
  IN p_image NVARCHAR(200),
  IN p_date_of_registration TIMESTAMP,
  OUT p_user_id INT
  )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, image, date_of_registration)
    VALUES (p_first_name, p_last_name, p_email, p_image, p_date_of_registration);
    SET @p_user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END;
```

Java

```
conn = engine.getDal().getConnection();
st = conn.prepareCall("{call partners.create_user(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
st.setString("p_first_name", user.getFirstName());
st.setString("p_last_name", user.getLastName());
st.setString("p_email", user.getEmail());
if(user.getImage() != null)
    st.setString("p_image", user.getImage());
else
    st.setNull("p_image", Types.NVARCHAR);
st.setTimestamp("p_date_of_registration", new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
st.registerOutParameter("p_user_id", Types.INTEGER);
st.execute();
userId = st.getInt("p_user_id");
```

Comment: If you call the procedure natively, do you get the expected result, too? And if you run the insert within java and select last_insert_id(), do you get the expected result as well?

Comment: good point... checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with procedure parameter and session variable - `p_user_id` vs `@p_user_id`. In your case the `p_user_id` is not set.

Change code in this way -

```
BEGIN
  ...
  ...
  ...
  SET p_user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END;
```

Comment: thanks, that fix it. can you point what the different between the two?

Comment: p_user_id is a procedure parameter, it is routine code scoped. @p_user_id is a session variable, it can be accessed from any part of the script, it is connection scoped.